# Put checkmarks in checkout after one step has been completed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a 5 step checkout and what I am trying to achieve is putting a checkmark in the previous steps after they have been completed.

I tried some javascript but it seems to me that I am using a wrong function

here is the html of the elements:

[image]

so basically when you move forward the previous steps will be highlighted as completed

[image]

edit: here is the code:

```
<ul class="checkout-steps steps-5">
                    <li class="cart">
            <a href="https://www.eyerim.sk/checkout/cart/">
                <small>Krok</small>
                <em>Môj Košík</em>
            </a>
        </li>
                            <li class="address">
            <a href="https://www.eyerim.sk/stepcheckout/step/address/">
                <small>Krok</small>
                <em>Adresa</em>
            </a>
        </li>
                            <li class="active payment">
            <span>
                <small>Krok</small>
                <em>Spôsob platby</em>
            </span>
                        </li>
                            <li class="review">
            <span>
                <small>Krok</small>
                <em>Spolu</em>
            </span>
        </li>
                            <li class="success">
            <span>
                <small>Krok</small>
                <em>HOTOVO</em>
            </span>
        </li>
        </ul>
```

and here is the code of the currently
 active step

```
<li class="active payment">
            <span>
                <small>Krok</small>
                <em>Spôsob platby</em>
            </span>
                        </li>
```

Comment: please copy your code into the question. The image links aren't working.

Comment: do you need to add the active class to the element you want highlighted?

Comment: Oh sorry i see. You need to make the completed. There are many ways to do that.

you can create a completed class with CSS and have that trigger the visibility of the green tick. or add the green tick as a background image.

Comment: I think you need to paste your code here for a proper answer because it's not clear what code is nested in the image

Comment: Please provide the minimal code you wrote for the steps. Is it a list? Do you have a class that identifies the current step?

Comment: yes, that what I need. when the user will be lets say on step 3, the previous 2 steps will have the class changed and the new checkmark image will be there. I just dont get the javascript function which will do that.

Comment: code added to the main post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Icon change on click in `JS`, change the icon as per requirement.

JS

```
function change (iconID){
      if(document.getElementById(iconID).className=="fa fa-chevron-up"){
        document.getElementById(iconID).className = "fa fa-chevron-down";
      }else{
        document.getElementById(iconID).className = "fa fa-chevron-up";
      }
    }
```

HTML

```
<i id="icon1" onclick="change('icon1')" class="fa fa-chevron-up" aria hidden="true">
```